# Dice/Jaccard Coefficient Optimization in Tensorflow

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to optimize my network with either Dice's or Jaccard's coefficient. My issue is an image segmentation problem so my output is a tensor of shape (1, 256, 256, 11). In order to calculate the intersection of my output and the truth image I take

```
tf.argmax(output, axis = 3)
```

which returns a datatype of "int" which tensorflow optimizers (specifically `AdamOptimizer`) don't seem to take so I then convert this to a float with

```
tf.cast(tf.argmax(output, axis = 3), tf.float32)
```

However, it doesn't seem as though there is a gradient defined for tf.cast (or tf.argmax for that matter). Has anybody been able to sucessfully implement

Answer (score 5):

The operation `tf.argmax()` is not differentiable, that's why the gradient is not implemented. You can not optimize Jaccard directly, because it is not differentiable.

The same happens with accuracy, when you train a classifier you optimize a differentiable loss even if you only care about the accuracy, because the accuracy is not differentiable.

So there isn't a solution to your problem, you'll have to use a loss function that you can differentiate and optimize that loss instead of the jaccard.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem today and I realized that it is not possible to calculate dice loss without `tf.argmax()` function, which has no gradients.

One possible solution for similar situations would be to use generalized dice coefficient, i.e. use softmax predictions in combination with 'one_hot' ground truth image as an inputs.